# Perl scripting for syslog

Tags: perl

I'd like a more efficient way for my Perl Script to parse through syslogs.

My script runs on a cron on an hourly basis to output some statistics. I noticed it takes almost 5-10 minutes to complete as the day progresses (syslogs are archived daily) because the syslog files are several GB in size and the script does a simple:

```
open LOG, $logfile or die "fatal error. Could not open $logfile"
```

The problem is that initially the first hours worth of logs are the first lines in the logs. As the day progresses, the "current hour" of log entries in the syslog are now from, let's say lines 600000 to 700000. So each hour it gets slower and slower.

A complex approach would be to have a grep run against the file based on the time and store the results in a tmp file then have my perl script process the tmp file, then remove the tmp file, repeat.

Is there a more programmatic way to ensure I'm not rereading the thousands of lines everytime?

SK

Comment: The time it takes to open a file is independent of how big it is. 5 or 10 minutes is a long time to search even a few gigabytes. Could you post the actual search code?

Comment: I added a print after the `while (<LOG>) { $count++; print line $count\n"` and its incrementing at a rate of 5000 lines per second. However, by the 7th hour, my current hour's worth of logs are on lines 600000-70000. The code is pretty long and on a box not on this network so hard to port over, thus the small snippet. Basically, I don't want to reread lines 1-600000 for every hour that I'm checking the log for the current hour's worth of logs. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The actual search is right after the print above which says `if ($_ =~ /^$time_search_str/ ) {...do some stuff`

Comment: Could you add the actual code to the post? It's hard to follow additions to the question in comments. Editing the post is easier to read and more likely to be seen by others. You'll probably have to remove the business logic, but the basic "read the file and look for the right timestamps" should be postable.

Comment: Sorry Schwern, read above, its on a non internet attached box and is not easily typed. I'm still learning how to post in a much more readable way, apologies.

Comment: I apologize for these questions in advance, but I've seen things here you wouldn't believe. 1) Do you open the file exactly once? 2) Do you read it with simple `while (my $line = <LOG>) {...}`? 3) Do you close the file exactly once? Again, sorry, I don't want to insult you. It's just because you cannot show code.

Comment: @PerlDog no problem. I do open the file just once using a `while (<LOG>) {`. I then process the lines using the default variable `$_` As far as closing the file, I do not explicitly say `close LOG;` I simply allow the code to exit the while loop once all the lines have been read. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a bunch of possible solutions.

---

First is to implement hourly, instead of daily, log rotation. Then your program only has to read the hourly log file. This is probably a good idea in general if your logs are getting into the gigabyte range per day.

---

If that's not possible, there's probably work which can be done to improve the performance of your search code. The first step would be to run a code profiler like [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) to find out where your program is spending its time.

---

Instead of doing a linear search you can do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).  Assuming your logfile entries are something like this:

```
Mar 22 01:22:34 blah blah blah
Mar 22 01:22:35 blah blah blah
```

`seek` to the halfway point of the file, read a partial line, throw it out, and read the next full line.  Check its timestamp.  If its too new, `seek` backwards half the remaining space, if it's too old, `seek` forward half the remaining space.  Repeat until you find the start of the hour.

For a billion records this will take about log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>30</sup>) or 30 steps.

---

Another option is to read the file backwards.  Start at the end (the newest log entry) and work back until you hit the start of the hour.  [File::ReadBackwards](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards) can do this fairly efficiently.

---

You could change your log statistics program to write its results to a database including the position in the log file of the last record it wrote.  Then the next time it runs it `seek`s to that position, verifies it's correct, and reads forward from there.

---

Finally, consider using a database.  You can have syslogd log to a database itself, this avoids the overhead of every program having to log to the database.  For example, [rsyslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsyslog) and [syslog-ng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng) can do this.

Comment: All great suggestions Schwern. I definitely have no control over the log rotation, but I thought of that as well. As far as profiling, that is an interesting tool, I determined the cause via the $count printouts. They printed out for a few minutes until finally I hit my search string and my code began to process.  <br/> I like the binary search method, reminds me of the half step method. I'm assuming `seek` is a PERL function? <br/> I did think about reading the file backwards, but not sure how it would be stored in the variable. In otherwords would I have to reverse process it.

Comment: The database is something I'm pushing for, especially because they desire historical statistics, however, I'm focused on the first step which is the fixing the processing which seems to take for ever, hence the post.

Comment: [`seek()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) is a Perl function, its common to most programming languages, and it moves the cursor around the file like you would in an editor. As for the database, you don't need to wait for someone to install a database server, you can use [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

Comment: The script could also simply remember the last line number processed and then start processing the file after this line when next run.

Comment: @dgw Not the line number, because it will have to read the whole file to get back to that line number (at least it doesn't have to also parse each line). Instead remember the byte position of the end of that line. Then it can `seek` straight there next time. That's the second to last suggestion in the answer.